# Search and Highlight text in an Image in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, material-ui

I am doing a project in react, where I would allow the user to search for text in an Image and also zoom in to that particular area of the Image. Can anyone suggest me any Libraries I can use to achieve that particular use-case?

I have tried react-bounding-box, which allows us to segment the images. But it doesn't segment text.

I have also tried react-img, which also didn't help my use-case.